# How can I join an ics remote calendar?

Tags: mac, calendar

I have to join a shared calendar for which i have a https url (like `https://servername:5006/calendar/calendar.ics`)

How can I join it on the Calendar App?
I only managed to subscribe to it, although when subscribing I cannot add my own events but only see what others are publishing.

It works perfectly using Thunderbird Lightspeed, but I want to be able to use the Calendar App for my convenience

Answer (score 1):

Solution found by myself:
I needed to create a new local calendar (possibly importing the ics file downloaded from the server) then publish it at the same address such that it is now localized there

Comment: this solution is not behaving properly as it overwrite the remote file without updating first, in particular it looks like is only pushing changes to the remote file and reading them as it should in a shared calendar

Answer (score 0):

`File → New calendar subscription...` or <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>. Then insert your url in the text field.

Comment: subscribing to the calendar is not the solution I want because I lose the ability to add events and modify them.